# Selenium convert Xpath (ID and Class) to CSS selector

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

Trying to understand how to convert this Xpath to CSS locator.

```
 //div[@id='State']//input[@class='state-dropdown list']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> //div[@id='State']//input[@class='state-dropdown list']

The valid `cssSelector` for this `xpath` would be :-

```
div#State input.state-dropdown.list
```

[From CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

- [`CSS #id Selector`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp) use to locate an element with their id attribute value
- [`CSS element element Selector`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp) use to locate element that is inside paranet element. In your case, `cssSelector` would be locate `<input>` elements that would be inside `<div>` element.
- [`CSS .class Selector`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) use to locate an element with their class attribute value

Answer (score 1):

the cssSelector for above xpath is

```
div#State input.state-dropdown.list
```

here `# represents id` and `. represents class name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
div#State input.state-dropdown.list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
div#State * > input.state-dropdown.list
```

For more reference follow the link:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp